# UIImagePickerController delegate is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Using the code below it opens the camera but fails to call the picker delegate method. I'm getting no error messages.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class RecVidController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        RecVidController.startRecord(delegate: self, sourceType: .camera)
    }

    static func startRecord(delegate: UIViewController & UINavigationControllerDelegate & UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) else { return }

        let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
        mediaUI.sourceType = sourceType
        mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
        mediaUI.delegate = delegate
        delegate.present(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func video(_ videoPath: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo info: AnyObject) {
        let title = (error == nil) ? "Success" : "Error"
        let message = (error == nil) ? "Video was saved" : "Video failed to save"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

extension RecVidController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                       didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        guard let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String,
            mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
            let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL,
            UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path)
            else { return }

        // Handle a movie capture
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, #selector(video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

extension RecVidController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger. What code path does your app actually take when you pick a video?

Comment: it goes into startRecord then records a video....then I'm expecting it to call imagePickerController but it does not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this declaration:

```
private func imagePickerController(
    _ picker: UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
```

You have declared this method `private`, so Objective-C has no way of knowing that it exists. Thus, it can't call into it.

Basically, Cocoa looks to see whether this method is implemented, discovers that it *isn't* (because you've hidden it), and gives up. There's no visible penalty, because this delegate method is optional, and when it is not implemented, Cocoa dismisses the picker for you when the user is finished with it.

So just delete `private` and you should be good to go. This exposes the delegate method to Objective-C, and so it will be called.

<sub>(You do not have to say `@objc` to expose it to Objective-C, as you would if this were your own function, because you've declared we adopt UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, which is an Objective-C protocol.)</sub>

Comment: You might want to watch WWDC 2018 video 408; declaring a method `private` and thus hiding it from Objective-C can actually be a _good_ thing, because it keeps down the size of the generated header. However, in this instance, it's a bad thing; you _want_ Objective-C to see this method.

Comment: fyi this is swift ;-)

Comment: FYI Cocoa, where UIImagePickerController (and everything else in UIKit, Foundation, and all the rest) comes from is Objective-C. The fact that you don't understand you're talking to Objective-C is in fact the problem.

Comment: A good mental exercise for you might be: Think hard about `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` and ask yourself: _who_ is supposed to call it? When you program iOS, you are _talking to someone_. You need to get yourself a mental picture of who it is and what it expects from you. That is the heart of iOS programming.

Comment: Thank you. You are clearly a master! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when delegate methods were not called by program.

The `imagePicker.delegate = self` should be **NOT** in viewDidLoad() method but in method which opens gallery. Like this:

```
func openGallery()
    {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```